# handling threadstateexception when [STAThread] is already listed above main()

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, exception

I have an installer that i am trying to add a form that pops up when it reaches a certain point in the install process.

This form is used to get desired folder locations to be used as the locations of the pieces of the install. The form comes up fine and if i manually punch in the folder locations it works. But what user would want to manually do this right? so i added a button that is suppose to act as a folder dialogue however, when this is clicked on i get a threadstateexception.

After researching this problem the most common reason this happens is because you're missing [stathread] over the main method of your program. This has already been added to my installer so i was hoping someone could let me know what exactly i'm doing wrong with this as winforms is not something that i've spent much time working with.

here is the code i'm using with this particular problem.

The call to open the form.

```
OracleDriveLocations ODL = new OracleDriveLocations();
ODL.ShowDialog();
```

the code for the folder dialogue button.

```
this.folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
DialogResult rst = this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (rst == DialogResult.OK)
{
  string path = this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
  logger.DebugFormat("Data Files path was changed to {0}.", path);
  this.DataFileLocationTB.Text = path;
}
```

i've also tried using a temporary thread to run this but to no avail as such:

```
var t = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() => 
{
                this.folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
                this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
                DialogResult rst = this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (rst == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string path = this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                    logger.DebugFormat("Data Files path was changed to {0}.", path);
                    this.DataFileLocationTB.Text = path;
                }
}));

t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

**The stack trace as requested**

```
         at System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)   
    at DM.Installer.OracleDriveLocations.DataFilesButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PIDirect_Access\Installer\PIDirectAccessInstaller64Bit
        - try 2\DM.Installer\OracleDriveLocations.cs:line 51   
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)   
 at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)   
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)    
    at      System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)    
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    
    at DM.Installer.SchemaHandler.Install(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e, InstallerData data) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PIDirect_Access\Installer\PIDirectAccessInstaller64Bit
        - try 2\DM.Installer\SchemaHandler.cs:line 100    
    at DM.Installer.InstallProgressPage.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PIDirect_Access\Installer\PIDirectAccessInstaller64Bit
        - try 2\DM.Installer\InstallProgressPage.cs:line 404    
    at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

any help or suggestions on what i'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Slaks the stack trace has been added

Comment: You still don't have newlines.

Answer (score 1):

> at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

There's your problem.

This code is running on a BackgroundWorker thread, which is never STA.
Do that on the UI thread instead.